# Using Morphia @Reference with ArrayList<> - Specifying order, offset and limit

Tags: java, playframework, morphia

I'm trying to use Morphias references. The problem is, when I specify code like this :

```
@Reference
public ArrayList<NotificationParticipant> users;
```

The code above is from Notification entity which can have infinite amount of participants, so this will result in loading all the participants. I want to specify something like this to load just some Participants (because I don't need all of them)

```
@Reference( order="-createdAt" limit=3 )
public ArrayList<NotificationParticipant> users;
```

Is there a way to do this in Morphia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available by default. You can lazily load referenced users, but that's it. You'll need to build your own implementation.

One thing to watch out for: If you only load an entity partially, what happens if you save it back to the database? Do you want to merge the old and the new data or do you only want to store the current state?

Comment: While using reference to ArrayList, I want the field to be @Transient. No reference value is stored in the current class, but other collection documents have their references to the first collection documents. That way, I just insert/remove the references from the second collection. There's no need of merge in my solution.